# Homework question - C++ updating an already identified variable

Tags: c++

I have a question from my C++ textbook that asks:

update the value of an int variable x by adding 5 to it.

my x variable is initialized at 25 right now.

How would I do this? (I apologize if this seems confusing...feel free to correct me if I said a word that was incorrect)

I used yahoo and they said the answer is

```
int x=1; 
x=x+1;
```

This makes no sense though... it clearly says to add 5. 
Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: So what happens if you replace 1 with 5?

Comment: Here's some documentation on operators that might help you understand. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: You used yahoo? I see the problem.

Comment: It seems you are taking an explorer's approach to programming, trying to *discover* the solution to your problem. Programming is a creative activity that generally requires you to *create* your solution. The solution to your exact problem rarely already exists. Online resources can provide you with examples of similar solutions or explain certain approaches but you should not try to find whole solutions. Try to understand why and how the examples you find work first. You should then be able to produce solutions for *your* problem.

Comment: The chapter of the book you are using should have gone over this already.  If it hasn't, throw it away and get [one of these instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3):

Terminology wise you should be saying "How do I alter a variable?"

Given a variable `x` like:

```
int x = 25;
```

You can alter it using *assignment*:

```
x = 90; // Set to 90
x = x + 5; // Set to x plus 5
x = x * 2; // Set to x times 2
x = -5; // Set to negative 5
```

All of these are valid assignments.

You can also use other operators that make alterations to `x` while being less verbose about it:

```
x += 5; // Add 5, same as x = x + 5
x *= 2; // Multiply by 2, same as x = x * 2
x++; // Increment, vaguely similar to x = x + 1 but with lots of caveats
```

There's a [whole bunch of operators that you can use as listed in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) that are worth reading about.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

`x = x + 5`

Short explanation: it reads the value from x, adds 5 and writes the result to your variable x.